check the value of variable using IF and REF field code in MS Word
I want a text to be displayed based on the value of a field code variable.  The first field code sets a variable { SET a 0 }.  The 2nd field code displays text based on the value of the variable { IF { REF a } = 0 "zero" "one" }.
However, it outputs REF.


Your code is fine, but you should enter the inner REF field with ctrl-F9, just like the outer IF. From the image, it seems you entered curly brackets instead.

Thank you for checking my code and suggest the insert field short cut.  I will update my answer.

As suggested by Paul, I have to use an Insert Field shortcut to insert {REF a} field code instead of typing the curly brackets manually.
Here's my inconvenient way of doing this (before I read Paul's comment.)

Add a new {REF a} field code.
Select the whole field code.  Cut it.
Delete {REF a} in IF.
Paste the field code.

